# Multiple indices into a 1D array

Tags: c++, arrays

I was trying to implement strongly connected algorithms from different sources.  I found one that confuses me at http://www.oneous.com/Tutorial-Content.php?id=18

The reason for my confusion is this line:

```
if (used[v[s][i]] == 0)
  DFS(v[s][i]);
```

We have declared `v` as a one-dimensional vector, but here it is used as a 2-dimensional vector.  I think this is an error but can't figure out how to fix it.  Please help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`v` is declared as:

```
vector<int> v[1005];
```

i.e. an array of vectors.  So the first index accesses into the array, the second accesses into the vector.

Answer (score 1):

`v` is an array of vectors. So `v[1]` is a `vector<int>` at position 1, and `v[1][2]` is an integer at `vector<int>` position 2.

Vector class allows that because it overrides `[]` operator

Comment: i did not know such kind of  feature,then comes question why we need two dimensional vector declaration?